# Create multiple tables with relationships without checking "references" in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I was trying to migrate a SQL Server DB to Postgres.

As an example, Consider we have 3 tables - A, B & C.

B contains foreign keys of A & C.

But we are creating table in the order of A, B then C.

Since there is no "Table C" available, the "Table B" creating will throw error saying there is no relation exist.

So is there any way to "Not check references" during table creation within a transaction or session?

In real scenario, I have around 76 tables.

Comment: You typically create all tables first, then run the ALTER TABLE statements to define the foreign keys. There is no other way.

Comment: No need to get complicated. Just change the order  A,C,B.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints can be added to a table at any time, not just during table creation, so one option would be to create all the tables first, and then all the constraints.

So rather than:

```
Create Table AAA (
  ... Constraint fk_AAA_BBB Foreign Key (BBBcode) References BBB (BBBcode)
)
Create Table BBB (
  ...
)
```

You would run:

```
Create Table AAA (
  ...
)
Create Table BBB (
  ...
)
Alter Table Add Constraint fk_AAA_BBB Foreign Key (BBBcode) References BBB (BBBcode)
```